# filepond and jquery addfiles loading error

Tags: jquery, filepond

I am trying to add files to my filepond but I keep getting an error "Error During upload"
Below are the JS Codes

```
Editpond = FilePond.create(
                document.querySelector('.file_attachment' + id), {
                    allowMultiple: true,
                });
                Editpond.addFiles('assets/uploads/files/06-30-2021_063014_slides.pdf','assets/uploads/files/06-29-2021_043536_slides.pdf');
```

This is the error I get.
[image]

In my chrome inspect element, I get this error

[image]

Upon disabling my IDM software, everything works perfectly
[image]
What might be the possible solution to this?
As on my form data submission, the error doesn't submit the file added, but it's able to send the file through the form data when it loads successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to a Chrome extension.

> Most likely you will see this error appear if you are using an extension such as Adblock or a browser safety plugin.

See below:
https://www.keycdn.com/support/how-to-solve-err-blocked-by-client

Comment: Thanks @Rik. But the issue here is that my internet download manager is the plugin trying to disrupt the file from loading. If I disable, it works perfectly but is there a way to prevent my file download manager from interrupting with filepond? as when deployed might cause issues for users.

Comment: I don't know. FilePond is using basic file loading / processing functionality so I suspect you'll run into trouble on more sites.